# Login error in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm having a bit of an issue.
I am finishing work on my first mvc app and I'm using the default Login and Registration Actions.They work, but when I seed the db with initial data I add an administrator user(the user is added to the database correctly). When I try to login as this user - I cannot pass the authentication, I get an error saying "wrong password"

Any help would be strongly appreciated.(I really have no clue)

I am using mvc 5,identity 3.0, entityframework 6.

My account controller actions are

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    //        if (ModelState.IsValid){
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                    return View("Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
      //      }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
         //   return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = model.UserName, Name = model.Name, Email = model.Email,BirthDate = model.BirthDate, LastName = model.Name };
                PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> a = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {                                       await_signInManager.SignInAsync(user,isPersistent:false);
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");

                    _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }


            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

And this is my data seed method (with class). it is called in the StartupCS after setting the routing.

```
     public static async void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {


            var context = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            bool need= false;
            try
            {
            if (context.Users.Count() == 0)
                need = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {     }



            if (need)
            { 
            string[] roles = new string[] { "Administrator", "User" };

            foreach (string role in roles)
            {
                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

                if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
                {
                    await roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
                }
            }


            await context.SaveChangesAsync();


            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Name = "Admin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                Email = "admin@gmail.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@GMAIL.COM",
                UserName = "Owner",
                NormalizedUserName = "OWNER",
                PhoneNumber = "+923366633352",

            };


            var password = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
            var hashed = password.HashPassword(user, "secret");
            user.PasswordHash = hashed;

            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var result = userStore.CreateAsync(user);

                UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
//If I try this way - it keeeps on awaiting.                
         //      var result =await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "lol");

//the role seems to be working fine    
            var result2 = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Administrator");
           }

        }

    }
```

Comment: When you attempt to log in, are you trying the "secret" password on the login page? If you use the web template's built-in UI features to add a new user, can you log in as this new user? I'll try to reproduce your scenario if I get some time, to see if I can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.
Yes. I am trying to use secret as password, the template login works fine with users created through the registration.

Being very new to Asp.net - I can't really figure out the problem

Comment: What you  don't awating this line => `var result = userStore.CreateAsync(user);`

Comment: Does that matter here? 
The user is added to the database, so that's not the source of problem.
I don't think discussing performance is relevant here

Comment: It matter. Because if you don't await it the next instructions will execute while user is not really created.

Comment: CodeNotFound, have you read my post? 
I have stated, that the database has the admin entry and it exists.
The problem is that I get a wrong password notification on login

Howeever, adding await did not help the problem.